# pylab histogram get rid of nan

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, nan

I have a problem with making a histogram when some of my data contains "not a number" values. I can get rid of the error by using `nan_to_num` from numpy, but than i get a lot of zero values which mess up the histogram as well.

```
pylab.figure()
pylab.hist(numpy.nan_to_num(A))
pylab.show()
```

So the idea would be to make another array in which all the nan values are gone, or to just mask them in the histogram in some way (preferrably with some builtin method).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Remove `np.nan` values from your array using `A[~np.isnan(A)]`, this will select all entries in `A` which values are not `nan`, so they will be excluded when calculating histogram. Here is an example of how to use it:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pylab

>>> A = np.array([1,np.nan, 3,5,1,2,5,2,4,1,2,np.nan,2,1,np.nan,2,np.nan,1,2])

>>> pylab.figure()
>>> pylab.hist(A[~np.isnan(A)])
>>> pylab.show()
```

[image]

Comment: that works, thanks (i can only accept your answer in 4 min) Not entirely sure where you found that ~ statement in the documentation, but it works

Comment: @usethedeathstar [Here's the `~`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html), and [here are all of the bitwise operators as implemented in numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.bitwise.html)

Comment: If you didn't know about the `~` operator, you could just use `A[np.isfinite(A)]` which is possibly more what you want anyway.

Comment: note that outside numpy, `~` is not the same as `!` (`not`) and `~` will sometimes return something you don't expect (for example `-2`, which evaluates into `True`). Please either use `!`, or better yet spell out `not`