# Func to make histogram with normal curve for passed pandaDF column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I wanted to create a function that takes a df and col and returns a histogram with a normal curve and some labeling. Something that I can use and customize as I see fit for future data (will appreciate any recommendations to make it more customizable). This was made for the kaggle titanic training set, if needed, please download from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data). This function is working fine for columns without `NaN` values. Column `Age` has `NaN`, which is what I think is throwing the error. I tried to ignore `NaN` using [Error when plotting DataFrame containing NaN with Pandas 0.12.0 and Matplotlib 1.3.1 on Python 3.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564536/error-when-plotting-dataframe-containing-nan-with-pandas-0-12-0-and-matplotlib-1) where one of the solutions recommends using `subplot`, but it doesn't work for me; the accepted solution is downgrading `matplotlib` (my version is **'2.1.2'**, python is 3.6.4). This [pylab histogram get rid of nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090070/pylab-histogram-get-rid-of-nan) uses an interesting method which I am not able to apply in my case. How to remove the `NaN` ? Is this function customizable? Not primary question - Can I neatly do stuff like round mean/std, add more information?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mydf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

def df_col_hist (df,col, n_bins):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    n, bins, patches = ax.hist(df[col], n_bins, normed=1)

    y = mlab.normpdf(bins, df[col].mean(), df[col].std())
    ax.plot(bins, y, '--')

    ax.set_xlabel (df[col].name)
    ax.set_ylabel('Probability density')
    ax.set_title(f'Histogram of {df[col].name}: $\mu={df[col].mean()}$, $\sigma={df[col].std()}$')

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

df_col_hist (train_data, 'Fare', 100)
#Works Fine, Tidy little histogram. 

df_col_hist (train_data, 'Age', 100)
#ValueError: max must be larger than min in range parameter.

    ..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:29: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce
  return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:26: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce
  return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-c81b76c1f28e> in <module>()
----> 1 df_col_hist (train_data, 'Age', 100)

<ipython-input-70-1cf1645db595> in df_col_hist(df, col, n_bins)
      2 
      3     fig, ax = plt.subplots()
----> 4     n, bins, patches = ax.hist(df[col], n_bins, normed=1)
      5 
      6     y = mlab.normpdf(bins, df[col].mean(), df[col].std())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1715                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1716                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1717             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1718         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1719         if pre_doc is None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in hist(***failed resolving arguments***)
   6163             # this will automatically overwrite bins,
   6164             # so that each histogram uses the same bins
-> 6165             m, bins = np.histogram(x[i], bins, weights=w[i], **hist_kwargs)
   6166             m = m.astype(float)  # causes problems later if it's an int
   6167             if mlast is None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in histogram(a, bins, range, normed, weights, density)
    665     if first_edge > last_edge:
    666         raise ValueError(
--> 667             'max must be larger than min in range parameter.')
    668     if not np.all(np.isfinite([first_edge, last_edge])):
    669         raise ValueError(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `normpdf`is wrong, as it expects an array of x-values as first parameter, not the number of bins. But anyway, mlab.normpdf is deprecated afaik.

That said, I'd recommend to use `norm.pdf` from `scipy`:

```
from scipy.stats import norm

s = np.std(df[col])
m = df[col].mean()
x = np.linspace(m - 3*s, m + 3*s, 51)
y = norm.pdf(x, loc=m)   # additionally there's a `scale` parameter for norming against whatever in y-direction

ax.plot(x, y, '--', label='probability density function')
```

PS: For dropping `nan` in a pandas dataframe you have

```
df[col].dropna()
```

ie:

```
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(df[col].dropna(), n_bins, normed=1)
```

Comment: Freeeeezzzee!!! drop the na, use the available values, make that histogram! 
Thanks..